# Rotation of polarization through optical activity

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

When a vertically polarized beam of light is incident on an optically active substance and rotated through some angle $\theta$, how is the degree of rotation related to the length of the path through the substance. In other words does the width of the material affect how much the electric field is rotated?

(Explain at high school level if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle of rotation is proportional to the length of the path the light ray spends inside the active material. This needs to happen because each bit of the path only 'knows' what's happening there and it does not interact with the rest of the material's optical activity. This means that the rate of rotation of polarization must be constant, i.e. that the rotation angle is proportional to the length of material traversed.

To be more precise, a linear polarization will be shifted by an angle 
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi\,\Delta n}{\lambda}L
$$
after passing through a length $L$ of material which has a refractive index difference $\Delta n$ between right- and left-handed circular polarizations. For more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rotation) as a good starting point.